# How to create Remote Event Receiver for List Added event?

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver

I want to attach Item Added remote event receiver to every new list created by user so I want to create remote event receiver for List Added event. Please help.

Comment: Use feature stapling for this.

Comment: Refer this link - https://mythoughttech.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/attaching-remote-event-receivers-to-lists-in-the-host-web/

Comment: This as well - https://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/03/13/remote-event-receiver-rer-for-host-web-using-sharepoint-provider-hosted-app-in-office-365sharepoint-online-environment/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for:

```
`private void AppInstalledMethod(SPRemoteEventProperties _properties)
    {
        using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(_properties, false))
        {
            if (clientContext != null)
            {
                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                clientContext.Load(web);
                clientContext.Load(clientContext.Site);
                clientContext.Load(clientContext.Site.EventReceivers);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation receiver = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation();
                receiver.EventType = EventReceiverType.ListAdded;
                OperationContext op = OperationContext.Current;
                Message msg = op.RequestContext.RequestMessage;
                receiver.ReceiverUrl = msg.Headers.To.ToString();
                receiver.ReceiverName = "EventForNewLibrary";
                receiver.Synchronization = EventReceiverSynchronization.Synchronous;
                receiver.SequenceNumber = 5000;
                clientContext.Site.EventReceivers.Add(receiver);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
    }`
```